# Where to put small subclass of NSObject, separate .h file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is probably a dumb question, but I'm new to programming and was wondering what ppl typically do.
Typically I use separate .h and .m files for all my classes.
I have a small class that just has a few properties on it that is a subclass of NSObject.
I use this class just to populate a UITableView.  I see that when I put it all in one of the related .m files, no one can see it unless I include the .m which I don't want to do because of a circular reference.  So do I just put it in the .h file?  Or do ppl always put it in separate .h and .m file for each class?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put in the .h file, unless you want the class to be private ( or certain parts of it ). A good way of hiding stuff from other classes is by defining a category inside the .m file.

Comment: I guess, you mean class extension (unnamed categories). There is a small but important difference: it is possible to declare properties in class extensions, but not in regular (named) categories.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like that, I often find myself defining the small "helper" class in the .m file for the class it supports, for instance one of the controller classes' .m file.

I put the `@interface` definition before the code that uses it, and the `@implementation` at the bottom.

That way I reduce the cutter of small files at the expense of the readability of the top of my .m file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd opt for putting separate classes in separate files - it makes navigating an unknown project soo much easier.

With a modern IDE the extra file is no hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Put the interface in the header and the implementation in the .m file, just like any other class. Putting all your code in the header is precisely equivalent to putting all your code in a .m file that you intend to import. There might be certain configurations of code where it happens to work, but it's a fragile design without much benefit. If you're going to give it its own file, go all the way and organize it properly.